# Population of Standard Deviation of $n$ numbers an integer?

Tags: number-theory, standard-deviation

I thought of this problem after thinking of how $n=3$ seems to have no solution to the below problem.

What numbers $n$ exist such that there are $n$ integers $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,...,a_n$ such that their standard deviation is a natural number? (Take the numbers as a population)

**Overall progress:** $n=1$ and $n=2k$ for $k$ is an integer both work.

**Progress for the current case I'm working on:** $n=3$ is very difficult to find, but thinking a lot, the current problem is to find $x^2+xy+y^2=6p^2$ for an integer $p.$ From there, I could use complex factoring, but the sum of squares is just as unwieldy.

I think that this can be proved/disproved using NT, but I'm stuck on how to go from there.

What do I do now?

Comment: If your $n$ integers are all equal, then the standard deviation is zero.  Do you not allow your $n$ integers to be equal?  Do you not consider zero to be a natural number?

Comment: Also for the case of $n=3$, if you have any three consecutive integers, their standard deviation will be $1$

Comment: Hm... I got it as $\sqrt{\frac23}...$ am I using a different function?

Comment: $$s = \sqrt{\frac{\sum{(a_i - \bar{a})}}{n-1}}$$ ?

Comment: I learned it as over $n$ oops... time to change it

Comment: Biaised or unbiaised ?

Comment: It depends on what kind of standard deviation we are taking. If these sets of $n$ integers are treated as a sample, then divide by $n-1$. But if you treat them as a population, then your formula is correct dividing by $n$ so it depends on the context of the problem

Comment: I don't know what biased and unbiased is... what's the difference?

Comment: Oh... I use population...